# Angular - unit tests not working in pipelines

Tags: angular, typescript

I upgrade angular in my projet from 14 to 15 but now when I launch unit tests sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't work in the gitlab pipeline

this is error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8eht.png)

I add this options in all files .spec.ts but also error:

```
teardown: {destroyAfterEach: false}
```

hwo to fix this error please